# Termination of structural induction

Tags: recursion, termination, agda, induction

I can't get Agda's termination checker to accept functions defined using structural induction.

I created the following as the, I think, simplest example exhibiting this problem.
The following definition of `size` is rejected, even though it always recurses on strictly smaller components.

```
module Tree where

open import Data.Nat
open import Data.List

data Tree : Set where
  leaf : Tree
  branch : (ts : List Tree) → Tree

size : Tree → ℕ
size leaf = 1
size (branch ts) = suc (sum (map size ts))
```

Is there a generic solution to this problem? Do I need to create a `Recursor` for my data type? If yes, how do I do that? (I guess if there's an example of how one would define a `Recursor` for `List A`, that would give me enough hints?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a trick you can do here: you can manually inline and fuse the definitions of map and sum inside a mutual block. It's pretty anti-modular, but it's the simplest method I'm aware of. Some other total languages (Coq) can sometimes do this automatically.

```
mutual
  size : Tree → ℕ
  size leaf = 1
  size (branch ts) = suc (sizeBranch ts)

  sizeBranch : List Tree → ℕ
  sizeBranch [] = 0
  sizeBranch (x :: xs) = size x + sizeBranch xs
```

Comment: Yes this is how I also do it when using `map`. It's really unfortunate really that the termination checker cannot go into the definition of `map` and see that everything is alright.