# Termination-checking of function over a trie

Tags: recursion, trie, termination, agda

I'm having difficulty convincing Agda to termination-check the function `fmap` below and similar functions defined recursively over the structure of a `Trie`. A `Trie` is a [trie](http://conal.net/blog/posts/elegant-memoization-with-functional-memo-tries) whose domain is a `Type`, an object-level type formed from unit, products and fixed points (I've omitted coproducts to keep the code minimal). The problem seems to relate to a type-level substitution I use in the definition of `Trie`. (The expression `const (μₜ τ) * τ` means apply the substitution `const (μₜ τ)` to the type `τ`.)

```
module Temp where

   open import Data.Unit
   open import Category.Functor
   open import Function
   open import Level
   open import Relation.Binary

   -- A context is just a snoc-list.
   data Cxt {} (A : Set ) : Set  where
      ε : Cxt A
      _∷ᵣ_ : Cxt A → A → Cxt A

   -- Context membership.
   data _∈_ {} {A : Set } (a : A) : Cxt A → Set  where
      here : ∀ {Δ} → a ∈ Δ ∷ᵣ a
      there : ∀ {Δ a′} → a ∈ Δ → a ∈ Δ ∷ᵣ a′
   infix 3 _∈_

   -- Well-formed types, using de Bruijn indices.
   data _⊦ (Δ : Cxt ⊤) : Set where
      nat : Δ ⊦
       : Δ ⊦
      var : _ ∈ Δ → Δ ⊦
      _+_ _⨰_ : Δ ⊦ → Δ ⊦ → Δ ⊦
      μ : Δ ∷ᵣ _ ⊦ → Δ ⊦
   infix 3 _⊦

   -- A closed type.
   Type : Set
   Type = ε ⊦

   -- Type-level substitutions and renamings.
   Sub Ren : Rel (Cxt ⊤) zero
   Sub Δ Δ′ = _ ∈ Δ → Δ′ ⊦
   Ren Δ Δ′ = ∀ {x} → x ∈ Δ → x ∈ Δ′

   -- Renaming extension.
   extendᵣ : ∀ {Δ Δ′} → Ren Δ Δ′ → Ren (Δ ∷ᵣ _) (Δ′ ∷ᵣ _)
   extendᵣ ρ here = here
   extendᵣ ρ (there x) = there (ρ x)

   -- Lift a type renaming to a type.
   _*ᵣ_ : ∀ {Δ Δ′} → Ren Δ Δ′ → Δ ⊦ → Δ′ ⊦
   _ *ᵣ nat = nat
   _ *ᵣ  = 
   ρ *ᵣ (var x) = var (ρ x)
   ρ *ᵣ (τ₁ + τ₂) = (ρ *ᵣ τ₁) + (ρ *ᵣ τ₂)
   ρ *ᵣ (τ₁ ⨰ τ₂) = (ρ *ᵣ τ₁) ⨰ (ρ *ᵣ τ₂)
   ρ *ᵣ (μ τ) = μ (extendᵣ ρ *ᵣ τ)

   -- Substitution extension.
   extend : ∀ {Δ Δ′} → Sub Δ Δ′ → Sub (Δ ∷ᵣ _) (Δ′ ∷ᵣ _)
   extend θ here = var here
   extend θ (there x) = there *ᵣ (θ x)

   -- Lift a type substitution to a type.
   _*_ : ∀ {Δ Δ′} → Sub Δ Δ′ → Δ ⊦ → Δ′ ⊦
   θ * nat = nat
   θ *  = 
   θ * var x = θ x
   θ * (τ₁ + τ₂) = (θ * τ₁) + (θ * τ₂)
   θ * (τ₁ ⨰ τ₂) = (θ * τ₁) ⨰ (θ * τ₂)
   θ * μ τ = μ (extend θ * τ)

   data Trie {} (A : Set ) : Type → Set  where
      〈〉 : A →  ▷ A
      〔_,_〕 : ∀ {τ₁ τ₂} → τ₁ ▷ A → τ₂ ▷ A → τ₁ + τ₂ ▷ A
      ↑_ : ∀ {τ₁ τ₂} → τ₁ ▷ τ₂ ▷ A → τ₁ ⨰ τ₂ ▷ A
      roll : ∀ {τ} → (const (μ τ) * τ) ▷ A → μ τ ▷ A

   infixr 5 Trie
   syntax Trie A τ = τ ▷ A

   {-# NO_TERMINATION_CHECK #-}
   fmap : ∀ {a} {A B : Set a} {τ} → (A → B) → τ ▷ A → τ ▷ B
   fmap f (〈〉 x)    = 〈〉 (f x)
   fmap f 〔 σ₁ , σ₂ 〕 = 〔 fmap f σ₁ , fmap f σ₂ 〕
   fmap f (↑ σ)    = ↑ (fmap (fmap f) σ)
   fmap f (roll σ) = roll (fmap f σ)
```

It would seem that `fmap` recurses into a strictly smaller argument in each case; certainly the product case is fine if I remove recursive types. On the other hand, the definition handles recursive types fine if I remove products.

What's the simplest way to proceed here? The [inline/fuse trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146928/termination-of-structural-induction) does not look particularly applicable, but maybe it is. Or should I be looking for another way to deal with the substitution in the definition of `Trie`?

Comment: Looks like some of your unicode is getting lost :(

Comment: Ah. Not on my installation of Ubuntu ;) Tell me where there are characters you can't see, and I'll try to post a friendlier version. (I wonder if it's the special font characters like ?)

Comment: I meant "letter symbols", not "font characters".

Comment: The inline trick is actually applicable - it just looks a bit weird. There might be a better way, but if you are happy with this solution, I'll post it as an answer. And yup, the unicode seems to be causing some trouble (not for my Agda-mode, since DejaVu Sans + Code2000 handles pretty much anything; Gist on the other hand...). https://gist.github.com/vituscze/8773710

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm checking now that I can generalise your solution to my existing code. By the way, what is it that doesn't appear to be displaying properly? (Unfortunately the Gist also looks fine to me.)

Comment: Subscript `t` and `s` are not displaying for me (I get the boxes with hex codepoint). Looks like stackoverflow's CSS has more font choices for the code blocks.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've pretty much dropped those subscripts now (I didn't really like them), so that gives me a good reason to drop the one or two that remain. I ran into a problem with your solution when I tried to add my base type of Nat back in - the reason being that a trie from Nat to A is implemented as a FiniteMap from Nat to A, and the functor instance for trie delegates to the functor instance for FiniteMap. Aargh. Maybe I need to partly inline that too...I'll experiment some more.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get it working by inlining an extra step. It feels a bit nasty (it does blow modularity out the window somewhat) but it works. I suggest adding your code as an answer; when I accept it I'll probably clarify what the full solution was.

Comment: By the way, I posted a new version of the question, without the problematic subscripts. (Let me know if there are still hex boxes anywhere.)

Comment: Well, there are no hex boxes on Gist anymore, so that's good. The inlining transformation feels nasty no matter what, I'd say. It could also work with sized types, but that's fairly intrusive to data definitions. I'll see if it works and if it does, I'll include it in the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've just done it for another function, and it's really unsatisfying. I also wondered whether using type environments rather than substitutions might help, because it would replace the use of a recursive function (in the definition of `Trie`) with an index tracking the environment. Unfortunately I don't really understand how the termination checker works, so I've no idea whether this will actually help, but I'll probably give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inline/fuse trick can be applied in (perhaps) surprising way. This trick is suited for problems of this sort:

```
data Trie (A : Set) : Set where
  nil  :                     Trie A
  node : A → List (Trie A) → Trie A

map-trie : {A B : Set} → (A → B) → Trie A → Trie B
map-trie f nil = nil
map-trie f (node x xs) = node (f x) (map (map-trie f) xs)
```

This function is structurally recursive, but in a hidden way. `map` just applies `map-trie f` to the elements of `xs`, so `map-trie` gets applied to smaller (sub-)tries. But Agda doesn't look through the definition of `map` to see that it doesn't do anything funky. So we must apply the inline/fuse trick to get it past termination checker:

```
map-trie : {A B : Set} → (A → B) → Trie A → Trie B
map-trie         f nil = nil
map-trie {A} {B} f (node x xs) = node (f x) (map′ xs)
  where
  map′ : List (Trie A) → List (Trie B)
  map′ [] = []
  map′ (x ∷ xs) = map-trie f x ∷ map′ xs
```

---

Your `fmap` function shares the same structure, you map a lifted function of some sort. But what to inline? If we follow the example above, we should inline `fmap` itself. This looks and feels a bit strange, but indeed, it works:

```
fmap fmap′ : ∀ {a} {A B : Set a} {τ} → (A → B) → τ ▷ A → τ ▷ B

fmap  f (〈〉 x) = 〈〉 (f x)
fmap  f 〔 σ₁ , σ₂ 〕 = 〔 fmap f σ₁ , fmap f σ₂ 〕
fmap  f (↑ σ) = ↑ (fmap (fmap′ f) σ)
fmap  f (roll σ) = roll (fmap f σ)

fmap′ f (〈〉 x) = 〈〉 (f x)
fmap′ f 〔 σ₁ , σ₂ 〕 = 〔 fmap′ f σ₁ , fmap′ f σ₂ 〕
fmap′ f (↑ σ) = ↑ (fmap′ (fmap f) σ)
fmap′ f (roll σ) = roll (fmap′ f σ)
```

---

There's another technique you can apply: it's called *sized types*. Instead of relying on the compiler to figure out when somethig is or is not structurally recursive, you instead specify it directly. However, you have to index your data types by a `Size` type, so this approach is fairly intrusive and cannot be applied to already existing types, but I think it is worth mentioning.

In its simplest form, sized type behaves as a type indexed by a natural number. This index specifies the upper bound of structural size. You can think of this as an upper bound for the height of a tree (given that the data type is an F-branching tree for some functor F). Sized version of `List` looks almost like a `Vec`, for example:

```
data SizedList (A : Set) : ℕ → Set where
  []  : ∀ {n} → SizedList A n
  _∷_ : ∀ {n} → A → SizedList A n → SizedList A (suc n)
```

But sized types add few features that make them easier to use. You have a constant `∞` for the case when you don't care about the size. `suc` is called `↑` and Agda implements few rules, such as `↑ ∞ = ∞`.

Let's rewrite the `Trie` example to use sized types. We need a pragma at the top of the file and one import:

```
{-# OPTIONS --sized-types #-}
open import Size
```

And here's the modified data type:

```
data Trie (A : Set) : {i : Size} → Set where
  nil  : ∀ {i}                         → Trie A {↑ i}
  node : ∀ {i} → A → List (Trie A {i}) → Trie A {↑ i}
```

If you leave the `map-trie` function as is, the termination checker is still going to complain. That's because when you don't specify any size, Agda will fill in infinity (i.e. don't-care value) and we are back at the beginning.

However, we can mark `map-trie` as size-preserving:

```
map-trie : ∀ {i A B} → (A → B) → Trie A {i} → Trie B {i}
map-trie f nil         = nil
map-trie f (node x xs) = node (f x) (map (map-trie f) xs)
```

So, if you give it a `Trie` bounded by `i`, it will give you another `Trie` bounded by `i` as well. So `map-trie` can never make the `Trie` larger, only equally large or smaller. This is enough for the termination checker to figure out that `map (map-trie f) xs` is okay.

---

This technique can also be applied to your `Trie`:

```
open import Size
  renaming (↑_ to ^_)

data Trie {} (A : Set ) : {i : Size} → Type → Set  where
  〈〉    : ∀ {i} → A →
    Trie A {^ i} 
  〔_,_〕 : ∀ {i τ₁ τ₂} → Trie A {i} τ₁ → Trie A {i} τ₂ →
    Trie A {^ i} (τ₁ + τ₂)
  ↑_    : ∀ {i τ₁ τ₂} → Trie (Trie A {i} τ₂) {i} τ₁ →
    Trie A {^ i} (τ₁ ⨰ τ₂)
  roll  : ∀ {i τ} → Trie A {i} (const (μ τ) * τ) →
    Trie A {^ i} (μ τ)

infixr 5 Trie
syntax Trie A τ = τ ▷ A

fmap : ∀ {i } {A B : Set } {τ} → (A → B) → Trie A {i} τ → Trie B {i} τ
fmap f (〈〉 x) = 〈〉 (f x)
fmap f 〔 σ₁ , σ₂ 〕 = 〔 fmap f σ₁ , fmap f σ₂ 〕
fmap f (↑ σ) = ↑ fmap (fmap f) σ
fmap f (roll σ) = roll (fmap f σ)
```

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate this. I've gone for the "sized types" approach, because of the impact on proofs of the inlining approach (plus it's horrible :). Can the size reasoning get tricky, if you're combining values of different sizes, say, rather than just preserving size as with `fmap`?

Comment: Also curious as to how the "sized types" approach compares with other general strategies, for example [Bove & Venanzio](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~venanzio/publications/General_Recursion_MSCS_2005.pdf).

Comment: @Roly: Well, I don't use sized types much, so I don't know their limits very well. But I suggest you check out examples and tests in the Agda repository: http://code.haskell.org/Agda/examples/ and http://code.haskell.org/Agda/test/ Just grep for `--sized-types`.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Vitus always impressed by the depth of your answers. Do you have a blog or something? :)

Comment: @copumpkin: That's always nice to hear, thank you! :) And no, I don't have a blog.

Comment: Great answer. @Roly: my understanding is limited, but I am under the impression that sized types typically (or always?) allow preventing the "inline/fuse" trick, and maybe more. Without sized types, sizes are checked locally (without considering the bodies of called functions), and "inline/fuse" works around that; but sized types allow propagating that sort of information non-locally — they expose the "size behavior" of a function's implementation in its interface, where it's visible during termination checking of callers.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Ok, that's an informative explanation. Thanks.